# Cannot run selenium test

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am new to automation testing. Currently downloaded selenium 4 and trying to automate login into a sample site.Please help me with this. Been struggling all day in this. And I can't even understand my error messages in the console[image]

Here is the code that I am trying to work with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/prashantmishra/Documents/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "oxd-button oxd-button--medium oxd-button--main orangehrm-login-button").click()

captured_page_title = driver.title
expected_age_title = "OrangeHRM"

if captured_page_title == expected_age_title:
    print("Test PASSED!")
else:
    print("Test FAILED!")

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the elements to be loaded on the web page.
The best approach to do that is to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits.
Also, I improved the validation you entered the web site by validation the Dashboard title is visible.
The following code works

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys("Admin")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("admin123")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "oxd-topbar-header-title")))
```

The result screen is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Prophet for your help. So do you suggest to use EC class for all kinds of elements?! How do I know usage of these things. Very new to Test Automation.

Comment: yes, we actually use it before almost all the iterations with web elements

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials about this. I can't point on the best since I didn't read all them. Maybe this, the Selenium official page https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/ ? Just try to read several of them implementing what theay are talking about

Comment: btw my browser closes instantly and I cannot see the dashboard after test execution. Anything I should know?!

Comment: Yes, this can be fixed too. But this is an additional, new question and it should be asked separately.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your selectors, I seem to get errors. The main culprit seems to be the button. I also introduced a sleep time to help the page load before looking for these selectors. This is what worked for me:

#### Note:

Have updated my code based on conversation with Prophet:

#### Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")

# Wait for the element to be present and visible on the page
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))
)
element.send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "orangehrm-login-button", " " ))]').click()


captured_page_title = driver.title
expected_age_title = "OrangeHRM"

if captured_page_title == expected_age_title:
    print("Test PASSED!")
else:
    print("Test FAILED!")

driver.close()
```

#### Output:

```
Test PASSED!
```

Comment: Using hardcoded pauses is not a good idea.

Comment: How is a sleep any worse than a webdriver wait ?

Comment: On one hand this pauses the code run for very long time, in your case 5 seconds, instead of continuing immideatelly when the element is clickable. On the other hand in case of low internet connection etc the test will fail while test using `WebDriverWait` will wait until the defined timeout that can be long enough while, again, in almost 100% cases the test will continue immediatelly when it is possible.

Comment: This code line just creates the webdriverwait object with timeout set to 10 seconds. I could use 30 or 60 seconds there, but is is just a timeout. Selenium driver pools the web page every several milliseconds checking for the desired condition. The code continues immediately when the condition is met. You need to learn about webdriverwaits